# Is there a limit in size to the program (.so) file?

Tags: solana-program, deploy, devnet

I keep having trouble uploading my contract to devnet and I'm basically unable to work/test things.  My current file size is 681kb for my `.so` file.  I'm wondering if there is a limit to the file size and if that might be contributing to my troubles with uploading the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current account data size limit is [10MB](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/757e46c3c7d93f40c6d733b0ca07996f3582cd8e/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L143).

681kb is an average program size and there are many programs that are above that.

Hard to tell what went wrong without seeing the logs but if the problems persist, you can try deploying from [Solana Playground](https://beta.solpg.io).